# How to have a word wrapping label in a UICollectionViewCell with a right anchor constrained to the cell's right anchor?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am making a custom UICollectionViewCell and inside it, I have a label that will be of variable length. I am trying to have the label constrained on the top, left, and right anchors, meaning it should stretch to fit these but not expand beyond them. However, when I set the right anchor to the right side of the cell, instead of the right side of the anchor being stretched to or having a maximum width determined by the right side of the cell, this constraint brings the right anchor of the cell to the right anchor of the label.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Currently, I am initially setting the sizes of the cells with this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: Feed.frame.width, height: 200)
}
```

Here are the constraints for the label.

```
locationText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: locationIconImage.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    locationText.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: locationIconImage.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

    locationText.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
```

Here is how the viewcontroller that holds the collection view is initialized:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Feed.dataSource = self
    self.setUpFeed()
    Feed.collectionViewLayout = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let width = Feed.frame.width
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 100)
        return layout
    }()
}
```

**What it looks like:**

Here everything looks fine, the cell is taking up the width of the screen and the label is being constrained to the cell and wrapping.

[image: one]

Here the right anchor constraint is pulling the right anchor of cell in towards itself.

[image]

Comment: You should specify cell size if you want the cell to match the screen width.

Comment: I did, the view controller is implementing func collectionView(collectionviewlayout: ) and setting the width of each cell to the width of the UICollectionView

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I updated the question with code. Thanks for looking into it

Comment: See that’s the thing. You have estimated item size. You need to use item size instead because you know what size it should be.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri What do I do then if the height is estimated and dynamic but the width is not? Right now the bottom of the cell is constrained to the button at the bottom of the view so that it is dynamic, but when I don't use estimated size, it fixes the previous problem but makes the height of the cells static.

Comment: You would have to set a width constraint for the container of the cell then. Any reason you are not using a tableView?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I ended up switching to a table view, it made more sense. Thanks for the help.